# Struts - Submit <html:form> within <logic:iterate>

Tags: java, session, struts, forms

I have jsp page where I iterate over a collection using `logic:iterate` and an `html:form` is displayed for each item. 
This works but every time I submit one of these forms and the page gets reloaded, all the remaining forms are filled with the last inserted values.
Probably something remains in session and since the forms are all of the same type they are all prepopulated.

This is my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<html>
<body>
    <html:img action="/viewMedia.do?method=viewImageThumb" paramId="idImage"
        paramName="image" paramProperty="idImage" />
    <logic:iterate name="regions" id="region">
        <p>
            <html:img action="/viewMedia.do?method=viewRegion"      paramId="idRegion" paramName="region" paramProperty="idRegion" />
            <logic:notPresent name="region" property="person">
                <html:form action="/AssignRegion.do" >
                    <html:text property="name" />
                    <html:text property="surname"  />
                    <html:checkbox property="usedForTraining" />
                    <html:hidden property="idRegion" name="region" />
                    <html:hidden property="idImage" name="region"/>
                    <html:submit />
                    <html:cancel />
                </html:form>
            </logic:notPresent>
            <logic:present name="region" property="person">
                <bean:write name="region" property="person.name"/>
                <bean:write name="region" property="person.surname"/>
            </logic:present>
        </p>
    </logic:iterate>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the input fields name attribute is not correctly prefixed when using the logic and html taglibs. Try using the [nested taglib](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.8/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-nested.tld) instead

```
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-nested" prefix="nested"%>
...
<nested:iterate ...
...
    <nested:form ...
        <nested:text ..
```

If you view the generated HTML, you will then typically see `<input name="regions[0].name" ...` rather than `<input name="name" ...`

I recommend always using the nested taglib as a replacement for the logic and html taglibs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like an issue with `logic:iterate`. Looking at your problem description it looks like you are using same form bean for all the mappings.

Check `struts-config.xml` to see if the scope of the form bean used in the action mappings is "session".

If it is "session", then you need to reset those properties of the form bean that do not require to be pre-populated in other pages being forwarded to.

If a particular property in the form bean is not reset, the session cached value of the property will be used on the resulting page(s) since form bean is held in "session".